# Prove the following statements involving repeating decimals

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I was asked to prove the following statements:

- A rational number $m/n$, where $\gcd (m,n) = 1$, has a  pure repeating decimal representation iff the descomposition of $n$ does NOT contain $2$ or $5$ as prime factors.
- A rational number $m/n$, where $\gcd (m,n) = 1$, has a mixed repeating decimal representation iff the prime decomposition of $n$ contains $2$ or $5$ and another prime factor

I don't know how to begin. To answer, you don't have to be strict.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose that when you wrote “has prime factors a power of $2$ or $5$”, you actually meant to write “only has prime factors distinct from $2$ and $5$”.

Comment: No, I typed it wrong. I am sorry. I meant it hasn't.

Comment: That `\text{gcd}` and `\gcd` do not always yield identical results can be seen here: $$ \begin{align} & 5\text{gcd}(a,b) \\ & 5\gcd(a,b)  \end{align} $$ The second of these, with `\gcd(a,b)` is standard for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The first should be a terminating decimal.  Note that if $n$ is as specified, it is a factor of some power of $10$.  I think what you mean by a pure repeating decimal is one that starts its repeat immediately after the decimal point.  Note that $\frac 17=0.\overline{142857}$ is a pure repeating decimal and $7$ has a prime factor other than $2$ and $5$.  The statement should be that you get a pure repeating decimal if $n$ has no factors of $2$ or $5$.  For the second, note that you can multiply $n$ by the right number of $2$s or $5$s to get a number of the form $10^kp$ where $p$ has no factors of $2$ or $5$.  Now use the fact that a fraction with denominator $p$ has a pure repeating decimal.

Comment: Could I get an extended  demonstration, please?

Comment: Have you just tried some?  I showed $1/7$.  What happens with $1/14?$  with $1/28?$